# AngularJs : How to use ng-click to show modal bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'am new in AngularJs. I try to make multilanguage web using AngularJs, Translator working fine. When i try to put translator result to `onClick` for executing my function it's not working. My function show Bootstrap modal  and replace modal content with some string than translated. I've write my code on [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/17700XE28uBppNatt5CH?p=preview&s=Un96C2bsRS9TwHAD:)

I hope someone can help me to learn and solved this

Here All mycode, other code in [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/17700XE28uBppNatt5CH?p=preview&s=Un96C2bsRS9TwHAD:)

```
index.html

 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@2.1.3" data-semver="2.1.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.1" data-semver="3.3.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.1" data-semver="3.3.1" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.0-beta.5" data-semver="1.4.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-resource@1.2.14" data-semver="1.2.14" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.14/angular-resource.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script>
       function here(f) {
        $.ajax({
                url: 'post.php',
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'Json',
                data: {test:'test'},
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        $('#smallModal').modal();
                        $('#contentin').html('Loading..');
                        $('#smallModal').html(f);

                }
            });
       }
    </script>
      </head>
      <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController as vm">
        <h1>Learn Angular</h1>
           <div ng-include="'header.html'"></div>
        <div ng-include="'content.php'"></div>
      </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: I have write code my [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/17700XE28uBppNatt5CH?p=preview&s=Un96C2bsRS9TwHAD). please for review. Thanks@isherwood

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use Angular to solve this?

You just need to change `onClick` to `ng-click`, and move `here` to myController's scope.

```
$scope.here = function here(f) {
         $('#smallModal').modal();
         $('#contentin').html('Loading..');
         $('#smallModal').modal(f);
}
```

That should solve the problem.

Comment: i use jquery because on function i want to post that result  with ajax jquery to databases

Comment: There's a [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) service in AngularJs for that. Why use jQuery?